# how to convert utf8 character whitch placed in latin charset incorectly?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I had sql database which set latin as its default charset. I insert into it some date whit utf8 charset. now all utf8 data shown as some "???? ???? ???"

Now i had correct it and all data insert truly.

My question is : How to convert incorrect data ("???? ???? ???") to correct utf8 ?

> 299, '941764104', '3040386379', 5, '?????', '????? ??? ????', '???', '3040386379', 13670620, '3040386379', '????????', '?????????', '????????', '????', 'نجف آباد', '????? ??', '19/50', '0', '?????', '???????? ????', '????????', '??????', '??????', '5', '??????', '???????', '????', '????', '????? ????? ??? ????????? ??????', '????', '???', '???? ?????', '???20000001?? 40000000 ????', '03434221987', '09303916242', '????? -??????? -? ??????????? ? 11', '941764104', '???????', '??', 'fme.jami@yahoo.com', 'p5572570860.jpg', 0, 10000000

Comment: what tool do you use to insert? and to check data?

Comment: i use jdbc.odbc package in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too bad.  The data in the table is `?`; the original text cannot be recovered.

When trying to use utf8/utf8mb4, if you see **Question Marks** (regular ones, not black diamonds),

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8.  Fix this.
- The column in the database is `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).  Fix this.
- Also, check that the connection during reading is utf8.